# Automate the process of including generated proto files into an Xcode project

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, protocol-buffers, grpc-swift

Our iOS app currently is using Google protobuffer [gRPC](https://grpc.io/) as our API layer to communicate between App and backend. And so we have these `.proto` files in our backend directory which will be converting to `.grpc.swift` and `.pb.swift` files by [gRPC-Swift-Plugins](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-swift#getting-the-protoc-plugins) and then consumed by the App.

This works okay, but the process of converting is very tedious, and we would like to automate the whole process.

###### Below is how we're doing it:

1. Delete previously copied directory, and copy all `.proto` files from backend (`.proto` files are maintained by backend devs) to App directory named "Protos" via a shell script
2. We already set up **Build rules** and include `.proto` files in **Compile Sources**. Following the steps from [an answer here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35841763/1727948)

Screenshot of the current setup in Xcode **Build Rules**: [image]

3. Whenever we build the project, `.pb.swift` and `.grpc.swift` are generated and putting into a directory named "generated" under the "Protos" folder.

##### Here are the problems:

1. If the backend added a new `.proto` files into the source directory, my script will only copy the files into the Protos directory but not included news files in the **Compile Sources** list.
2. Similar to the first problem, we need to manually set up **Compile Sources** in Xcode and that means if a new dev joins our team, he/she also needs to do the same setup again.
3. We sometimes need to refer to the `.grpc.swift` and `.ph.swift` files while coding. But If we add these files into Xcode and build the project again, Xcode will complain that these generated files are there like (Sorry, we're working on a private repo, so the project name and file names are replaced):

> Multiple commands produce '${user_path}/${proto_name}.pb.o':
>
> 1. Target '${my_project_name}' (project '${my_project_name}') has compile command for Swift source files
> 2. Target '${my_project_name}' (project '${my_project_name}') has compile command for Swift source files

Any answers or comments and suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It's interesting I didn't have those problems with Swift if I use the $DERIVED_FILE_DIR

```
protoc "$INPUT_FILE_NAME" --swift_out="$DERIVED_FILE_DIR" --proto_path="Your/proto/path"
```

I don't use the plugin because I've got the plugin installed in my `/usr/local/bin`

But I have exactly those problems when we use the output for cpp files.